# ValueInjecter: what to replace ConventionInjection with?

Tags: c#, .net-core, valueinjecter

Older versions of ValueInjecter had a `ConventionInjection` class; however that seems to have been removed even in the oldest version supported by .NET Core, so I can't switch my project to .NET Core without rewriting the code that uses `ConventionInjection`. What can I use to replace it?

Comment: It depends on what it is you are trying to accomplish I assume. Can you share the code that it is you need to replace? If you can't, take a look at [AutoMapper](https://automapper.org/), which is a convention-based object-object mapper.

Comment: I tried AutoMapper a long time ago, but ran into issues with it demanding I register every single type I want to map with it, which was prohibitive. Here is the code I need to replace: https://github.com/ekolis/FrEee/blob/master/FrEee/Utility/Extensions/CopyingExtensions.cs

Comment: you can use the `LoopInjection` instead https://github.com/omuleanu/ValueInjecter/wiki/custom-injections-examples